# Bash script: If any argument ($@) equals "foo" then… throws "too many arguments"

Tags: bash

In bash I can grab first argument via `$1`, second via `$2` etc.

I want to avoid hardcoding the amount of arguments because they can come in random order. Hence I wrote:

```
if [ "$@" == "--no-update" ]; then # this is line 14
    warning "The '--no-update' flag detected. Pull from origin master skipped."
else
    git pull origin master
fi
```

I call the script via:

> sh ~/code/dir/script.sh -f --no-update

but the args can also come in different order or quantity, like:

> sh ~/code/dir/script.sh -f -what-ever -abc --no-update -a -f -maybe-this

The output throws:

> line 14: [: too many arguments

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: which one is line 14?

Comment: `if [ "$@" == "--no-update" ]; then`

Comment: `$@` for example applied on `-f -what-ever -abc --no-update -a -f -maybe-this` will give you the string `-f -what-ever -abc --no-update -a -f -maybe-this`. The comparision with `--no-update` probably gives you the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"$@"` is a bit special in that it expands to *multiple* ‘fields’.

If you run your script with the arguments:

```
-f --no-update
```

Then:

```
[ "$@" = "--no-update" ]
```

Expands to:

```
[ "-f" "--no-update" = "--no-update" ]
# ⬑1   ⬑2
```

And `[` doesn’t know what to do with that (it can’t compare two strings to one string), hence ‘*too many arguments*’.

---

To test against all the arguments you could use:

```
for arg
do
  [ "${arg}" = "--no-update" ] &&
    warning "The '--no-update' flag detected. Pull from origin master skipped."
done
```

Comment: Thanks, your explanation was very helpful. Now I now how it works. Made some adjustments and everything works as expected.